# How do I add the chapter name in the header/footer?

Tags: chapters

Using `\fancyhead{\leftmark}` displays the chapter as

> CHAPTER N : CHAPTER_NAME

I need a normal format, like:

> Chapter_Name

that is, without "CHAPTER", the chapter number, colon and all-caps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@C. Peters was absolutely right, I just want to add an MWE to his/her answer:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum,fancyhdr} % 'lipsum' is only needed for the example.
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} % <--- Comment this line to see the difference.

\begin{document}
   \chapter{My first chapter}
   \lipsum
\end{document}
```

When you comment out C. Peters' `\renewcommand`:
[image]

When you use C. Peters' `\renewcommand`:
[image]

The header in the top right corner changes exactly the way you want it.

Comment: Ah, thank you. That's what I wanted. How would you remove the cursive?

Comment: I found it. `\markboth\textnormal{#1}` does the work.

Answer (score 1):

According to page 10 of the manual, which is included in the distributions, it is:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
 \markboth{#1}{}}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work if add this to the preamble.

Comment: Did you read the manual? Without an MWE it is impossible to help you, and without showing what you tried so far, you may be downvoted.